# A javascript console unusual error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just created a simple script trying to make a conditional statement but I don't know why and what is wring that I am getting his error in my console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Here is my code please let me know what is wrong with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#postcomment").click(function() {
    var name    = $('#name').val();
    var email   = $('#email').val();
    var comment = $('#comment').val();
    var post    = $('#pt').val();
    if(email == null && name == null && comment = null) {
        alert('Fields cannot be empty');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type   : "POST",
            url    : "include/get_data.php",
            dataType : "text",
            data   : {name : name, email : email, comment : comment, post : post, command : 'comment'},
            success  : function(data) {
                $("#all").apppend(data.commenting);
                $("#counts").html(data.count);
                document.getElementById('name').value = '';
                document.getElementById('email').value = '';
                document.getElementById('comment').value = '';
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Invalid here `comment = null`. Should be `comment == null`

Comment: Try `comment == null`.

Comment: Honestly, just search for the error message. The duplicate was the first result on google.com when searching for "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"...

Comment: The issue here is that `comment = null` is an assignment, but that mistake doesn't cause an error by itself. What actually causes that error is that you're using an assignment alongside a logical `&&`, which causes the line to be read like `(something && comment) = null`, but the result of the `&&` operator is not a valid reference to use in an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement has `comment = null` which is an assignment operator. Meaning you're accidentally setting `comment` to `null` when you do that. To do comparisons you need `==` or `===` equality operators.

```
if(email == null && name == null && comment = null) {
```

Should be

```
if(email == null && name == null && comment == null) {
```

Comment: am I not getting your point or not noticing as i do not see any difference

Comment: My God I am so blind lolx thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score -2):

In your if you have comment = null, change it to ==.

Comment: This was noted twice in the comments above. Instead of trying to farm rep from the typo, please vote to close the question as off-topic.